# Get CircleCI Latest Orb Version

Tags: api, circleci, orb

I'm looking to get the latest version of an Orb in CircleCI via an API.

For example

- **node 5.0.2**

[image: node 5.0.2]

- https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/node
- https://github.com/circleci-public/node-orb

Am I missing something in the [Docs](https://circleci.com/docs/) or the [API Docs](https://circleci.com/docs/api/v2/)?

Also tried looking at how Shields was showing the version [image: CircleCI Orb Version] but didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There's no CircleCI API endpoint for orbs (AFAIK). But you could achieve the result you're looking for with the [CircleCI CLI](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/local-cli/):

```
circleci orb info circleci/node|grep -i latest|cut -d "@" -f 2
```